# Qt - QGraphicsView without ScrollBar

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to show a picture in it's full view using QGraphicsScene. But when ever I put the QgraphicsScene inside the QGraphicsView, I am getting a scroll bar. I tried so many ways But all are went to veins. So can anybody tell me how to obtain the full view without the scrollbar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
QGraphicsView v;
v.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
v.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

To adjust the scrolling programmatically once these have been hidden, use one of the overloads of `v.ensureVisible()`.

Answer (score 19):

You might be getting scrollbars because the scene is larger than the usable area within the graphics view. By default, a QGraphicsView comes with a 1-pixel margin. To fix this, you can try:

```
QRect rcontent = graphicsView.contentsRect();
graphicsView.setSceneRect(0, 0, rcontent.width(), rcontent.height());
```

I had been getting scrollbars because I was manually setting the scene rect to the size of the graphics item I was adding -- which was as large as the QGraphicsView widget. I wasn't taking into account the margin.

Comment: Is there a way to just disable the 1-pixel margin? Your code fixes the problem for me, but it still looks like an obvious fix of a bad default.

Comment: Nope; this margin is hard-coded within `fitInView` (see QTBUG-11945). The only way to get rid of it is to write your own `fitInView`. There has been some discussion to expose the margin via an API but that has not yet made it into any Qt release.