# Programmatic scrolling with QGraphicsView and QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt, scroll, graphics

I would like to programmatically scroll a scene to the left / right, but I am not sure how to do that properly. Note that I do **not** want to have (visible) scroll bars.

I use a standard `QGraphicsView` + `QGraphicsScene` + `QGraphicsItem` setup. I have downsized it to the minimum, with one single `QGraphicsItem` (a `QGraphicsRectItem`) in the scene.

I have managed to achieve programmatic scrolling by setting my view like this:

```
// view setup
view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

and then, in another part of the code:

```
// programmatic scrolling
QScrollBar* const sb = view->horizontalScrollBar();
sb->setRange(0, 1000); // some values for experimenting
sb->setValue(sb->value() + 100 or -100); // some increment for experimenting
```

This works, but... scrolling through invisible scrollbars doesn't feel right.

I tried this more straightforward approach:

```
// programmatic scrolling - doesn't quite work
view->viewport()->scroll(100 or -100, 0); // some increment for experimenting
```

This code does scroll, but when the rectangle goes off the left edge of the view, and I reverse the scrolling direction (increment changed from `100` to `-100` in the call to `scroll()`), the uncovered part of the rectangle is not repainted. The reason is that `QGraphicsRectItem::paint()` is not called in that case (it is called when using the scrollbar method).

So, is there a way to get `viewport()->scroll()` work? Or some other simple way to achieve programmatic scrolling? Or is the artificial scrollbar method just the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the view assumes that it's smaller than its scene. If they're the same size, it won't move.

`QGraphicsView` can be set to [centerOn](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#centerOn) any position in scene coordinates. Use a timer to call `centerOn` to move the view one frame at a time.

Here's a working example: -

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QTimer>

class MyView : public QGraphicsView
{
private:

public:
    MyView(QGraphicsScene* pScene)
        : QGraphicsView(pScene, NULL)
    {}

    void AnimateBy(int x)
    {
        float updateFrequency = (1000/30.0); // ~30 frames per second

        QPointF currScenePos = sceneRect().center();

        int curX = currScenePos.x();
        int endPos = curX + x;

        int distanceToAnimate = (endPos - curX);

        // speed = dist / time
        float updatePosInterval = (float)distanceToAnimate / updateFrequency;

        printf("updatePosInterval: %f \n", updatePosInterval);

        static float newXPos = sceneRect().center().x();

        QTimer* pTimer = new QTimer;
        QObject::connect(pTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){

            newXPos += updatePosInterval;
            centerOn(newXPos, sceneRect().center().y());   

            // check for end position or time, then....
            if(newXPos >= endPos)
            {
                pTimer->stop();
                pTimer->deleteLater();
            }

        });
        pTimer->start(updateFrequency);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 10000, 20000);
    MyView* view = new MyView(&scene);

    QGraphicsRectItem* pRect = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100);
    pRect->setPos(scene.width()/2, scene.height()/2);
    scene.addItem(pRect);

    // timer to wait for the window to appear, before starting to move
    QTimer* pTimer = new QTimer;
    pTimer->setSingleShot(true);

    QObject::connect(pTimer, &QTimer::timeout,[=](){

        view->centerOn(pRect); // centre on the rectangle
        view->AnimateBy(100);
        pTimer->deleteLater();
    });

    pTimer->start(1000);
    view->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

So, we create the animation by moving the view frame-by-frame using the call to `centerOn`.

For simplicity, the code just deals with moving in one axis. To move in 2 axis, use 2D vector maths to calculate the interval position.

Comment: Yes, `centerOn()` would work. It's based on scrollbars (invisible in my case). I thought this is artificial, but it seems that this is how programmatic scrolling is done in Qt...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the view transformation with the `QGraphicsView::translate()` or `QGraphicsView::setTransform()`.

But keep in mind that you can't move the viewport "outside" the scene, so make sure that your scene rectangle is large enough.

Comment: No effect whatsoever :(

Comment: And how big is your scene rectangle (QGraphicsScene::sceneRect()) ? If it's completely inside the view, you can't scroll. But if it is bigger than view and you see just a part of it, you should be able to reach the borders of the scene rectangle with this QGraphicView::translate() method.

Comment: Even when I set the scene (much) larger than the view, `view->translate()` does not move the contents of the view. And there is an additional problem: `view->translate()` causes `QGraphicsRectItem::paint()` to be called even when the whole rectangle is visible. The scrollbar method did not have this problem (it internally moves the pixels with `memmove()`, which is more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, there is a dojo classes library with such class as PanWebView that allow QWebView to scroll smoothly with mouse without any scrollbars. [Take a look at sources](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2008/11/14/webview-and-panning-support/). It supports panning and can be suitable for mobile apps, but maybe it'll help you too.

PanWebView class looks like this

```
#include <QWebView>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QApplication>

class PanWebView : public QWebView
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    bool pressed;
    bool scrolling;
    QPoint position;
    QPoint offset;
    QList<QEvent*> ignored;

public:
    PanWebView(QWidget *parent = 0): QWebView(parent), pressed(false),     scrolling(false) {
    QWebFrame *frame = page()->mainFrame();
    frame->setScrollBarPolicy(Qt::Vertical, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    frame->setScrollBarPolicy(Qt::Horizontal, Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
}

protected:

void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent) {

    if (ignored.removeAll(mouseEvent))
        return QWebView::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);

    if (!pressed && !scrolling && mouseEvent->modifiers() == Qt::NoModifier)
        if (mouseEvent->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton) {
            pressed = true;
            scrolling = false;
            position = mouseEvent->pos();
            QWebFrame *frame = page()->mainFrame();
            int x = frame->evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollX").toInt();
            int y = frame->evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollY").toInt();
            offset = QPoint(x, y);
            QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);
            return;
        }

    return QWebView::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
}

void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent) {

    if (ignored.removeAll(mouseEvent))
        return QWebView::mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);

    if (scrolling) {
        pressed = false;
        scrolling = false;
        QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
        return;
    }

    if (pressed) {
        pressed = false;
        scrolling = false;

        QMouseEvent *event1 = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseButtonPress,
                                              position, Qt::LeftButton,
                                              Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
        QMouseEvent *event2 = new QMouseEvent(*mouseEvent);

        ignored << event1;
        ignored << event2;
        QApplication::postEvent(this, event1);
        QApplication::postEvent(this, event2);
        QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
        return;
    }

    return QWebView::mouseReleaseEvent(mouseEvent);
}

void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent) {

    if (scrolling) {
        QPoint delta = mouseEvent->pos() - position;
        QPoint p = offset - delta;
        QWebFrame *frame = page()->mainFrame();
        frame- >evaluateJavaScript(QString("window.scrollTo(%1,%2);").arg(p.x()).arg(p.y()));
        return;
    }

    if (pressed) {
        pressed = false;
        scrolling = true;
        return;
    }

    return QWebView::mouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent);
}

};
```

And usage:

```
PanWebView web;
web.setUrl(QUrl("http://news.google.com"));
web.setWindowTitle("Web View - use mouse to drag and pan around");
web.show();
```

Also did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528432/programmatic-qgraphicsview-scrolling-not-updating-properly) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513788/qt-qgraphicsview-without-scrollbar) topics? I think it can be usefull.

Comment: The two links you give in the last line of your answer use `centerOn()` and `ensureVisible()`, respectively. But these two methods internally use scrollbars, so nothing really new compared to the method I gave in my code snippet.